# AFNetworking singleton class issue

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2. Everything working fine. But here I am using singleton method. I want to change the header value when I logout and login again. But AFNetworking header value is not changing. It always keeping previous value. I put the break point inside the singleton method. It is going to first time only. After that it is not going.

This is my code.

```
+ (ContactSync *)sharedAPI
{

    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedApi = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APIURL_BASEURL] ];
        _sharedApi.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        _sharedApi.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        [_sharedApi.requestSerializer setValue:[CommonUtils loginToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
        NSLog(@"++++++++++++%@", [CommonUtils loginToken]);
        _sharedApi.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


    });
    return _sharedApi;

}
```

Here I used NSLog print the value. But it is only printing one time. Please help me.

Comment: Move your -setValue forHTTPHeader out of singleton declaration.

Comment: Why do you assign `_sharedApi.requestSerializer` twice?

Comment: Do you mean that you execute -setValue...forHTTPHeader somewhere else  and it still keeps the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`dispatch_once`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_43), therefore the block is only executed **once**. You have to get the `ContactSync` class object, and change the value on the request serializer.

```
[[ContactSync sharedAPI].requestSerializer setValue:[CommonUtils loginToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
```

Comment: This is correct answer.we have to use this to outside of dispatch_once   [_sharedApi.requestSerializer setValue:[CommonUtils loginToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];